# How can we read SAS data through readLines in R?

Tags: r, database, readlines

readLInes is giving error reading SAS data

```
readLines("C:/Users/shahch07/Desktop/364978/MEAP/Nig/2015/Prelim/Input/akure_city_res_design.sas7bdat")

 [1] ""    ")0" ")0" ")"   ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
[11] ""    ""    ""   
There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sas7bdat/sas7bdat.pdf

Comment: Basically i was going through this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5rMrI1e4kM) and looking for doing something similar with dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Since SAS use a compressed **binary** format to store sas7bdat, you may need a package, [sas7dat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sas7bdat/), to do it for you

- sas7bdat: read.sas7bdat()

Notice, there are 32/64 platform differences.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a dedicated import function, such as:

```
f <- "C:/Users/shahch07/Desktop/364978/MEAP/Nig/2015/Prelim/Input/akure_city_res_design.sas7bdat"
haven::read_sas(f) # haven
rio::import(f)     # or, a more convenient wrapper around haven
```

Use `install.packages(c("rio"))` to install those packages.